# AngularJS - Access UI element in template page via directive code

Tags: angularjs

I have the following AngularJS app

### template.html

```
<!-- Complex HTML code which contains other input -->
<input
    ng-keyup="enter($event)"
/>
<!-- Complex HTML code which contains other input -->
```

My directive code is as follow.

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('myDirective', function(appConfiguration) {
        return {
            templateUrl: 'template.html',

            controller: function ($scope) {
                $scope.enter = function(e) {
                    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                        // Perform some network operation...

                        alert('How to make my input lost focus?');
                    }
                };
            }
        }
```

I wish to make my input lost focus, when `enter` is pressed. However, I have no idea, how I can access `input`, when I'm in directive code.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

### **Accessing Element:**

You just need to inject **$element** in your directive's controller to access element.

### **Losing Focus on Enter**

After accessing, you just need to listen keydown events in your directive's link function. And you should blur(unfocus) the element whenever user press enter.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

.directive('loseFocus', function() {
    return {        
        controller: function ($element) {
            $element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
                if(event.which === 13) {
                    $element[0].blur();
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

And you don't need to pass ng-keyup parameter to directive, as it is directive's job to listen that event.

```
<input lose-focus>
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qzgt58f2/4/) for it.

**UPDATE**

It seems that my-directive is used to create multiple inputs. Then, the best approach here would be separating logic. my-directive can continue producing inputs and lose-focus directive can handle blur event on enter key.

Updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qzgt58f2/5/) is here.

Comment: What if my template contains multiple inputs? Note, my targeted input doesn't have an id, as it is generated via ng-repeat.

Comment: so you mean that my-directive creates multiple inputs? Than why won't you separate logic? my-directive can continue creating inputs, and lose-focus directive can handle blur event on enter key.

Answer (score -1):

just use following method signature to get hold of the element

```
controller: function ($scope, $element)
```

Comment: What if my template contains multiple inputs? Note, my targeted input doesn't have an id, as it is generated via ng-repeat. (I didn't downvote your answer)

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can use the controller or link function to pass the element and attributes.
Here's an example from [AngularJS doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). You can do the same for controller function.

```
.directive('myCurrentTime', ['$interval', 'dateFilter', function($interval, dateFilter) {

function link(scope, element, attrs) {
  var format,
      timeoutId;

  function updateTime() {
    element.text(dateFilter(new Date(), format));
  }

  scope.$watch(attrs.myCurrentTime, function(value) {
    format = value;
    updateTime();
  });

  element.on('$destroy', function() {
    $interval.cancel(timeoutId);
  });

  // start the UI update process; save the timeoutId for canceling
  timeoutId = $interval(function() {
    updateTime(); // update DOM
  }, 1000);
}

return {
  link: link
};
```

}]);